# Mediawiki Page Forms: How do you transclude user input from a form into a page without the section heading?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a form that takes user input and creates a page. Unfortunately, the page that is created includes the section heading, which I wish to avoid. I only wish to keep the name of the page, user input and nothing else.

Here is the Template page from my Mediawiki site:

```
<noinclude>
{{#template_params:Summary|Categories}}
{{#template_display:_format=sections}}
</noinclude><includeonly>
[[Category:Summary Article]]
{{#arraymap:{{{Categories|}}}|,|x|[[Category:x]]|\s}}
</includeonly>
```

Here's my Form code:

```
<noinclude>
This is the "Summary Article" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{#forminput:form=Summary Article}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
{{{for template|Summary Article}}}
==Summary==
{{{section|Summary|mandatory|rows=20}}}

==Category==
{{{field|Categories|input type=tokens|values from namespace=Category}}}

</includeonly>
```

The page that is created has it's name on top, then the label 'Summary' as the next heading, followed by the user input. I wish to remove the 'Summary' heading altogether. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Everything between
`<includeonly>  and  </includeonly>`
will show in your page.

So if you don't want Summary at the top of the summary section template then just remove "==Summary==". Same goes for the category heading below this.